# How to Generate Audit log Excel Report programmatically in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, csom

I am using below code to enable Audit report.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site site = targetCtx.Site;
Audit audit = site.Audit;
targetCtx.Load(site);                
targetCtx.Load(site.RootWeb);
targetCtx.Load(site.RootWeb.AllProperties);
targetCtx.Load(audit);
targetCtx.ExecuteQuery();
site.RootWeb.AllProperties["_auditlogreportstoragelocation"]= site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/AuditData";
// Enable all auditing is site collection level
site.Audit.AuditFlags = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AuditMaskType.All;
site.Audit.Update();
// Adjust retention time to be 1 days
//site.AuditLogTrimmingRetention = 1;
site.TrimAuditLog = true;                
targetCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I need to auto generate excel audit report to given document library automatically on daily basis using console APP.Is it possible?